# Does chef-solo support cookbook versions in run list items?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

The [documentation](http://docs.opscode.com/chef_solo.html) says:

> Chef Solo does not provide: Environments, for setting policy of
>   cookbook versions.

It says nothing about not supporting cookbook versions specified via [run_list](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Version+Constraints#VersionConstraints-CookbookVersionsinRunListItems) like:

```
{"run_list":["recipe[nginx@1.2.3]"]}
```

But I have tried running solo with run_list requiring a greater version of cookbook than available and it just goes through fine. Can you confirm that versions just aren't supported by solo, wherever. Solo should probably warn at least though.

Comment: I have the same problem and it is frustrating as chef-solo doesn't support environments which is the other place I would put a cookbook version...but what it says is correct – chef-solo just doesn't support cookbook versions.

Comment: How should that be possible? `chef-solo` can only run the cookbooks that are available in the file system. It doesn't have a store (like the chef server) to request a certain version.

Comment: It could at least error out when the stated version isn't available on the file system

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, this is not possible in Chef Solo. Chef Solo operates on a list ("directory") of cookbooks, so it's relatively impossible for multiple versions to exist for the same cookbook. I agree, maybe Chef Solo should produce a warning. Perhaps open a ticket?